# insert block of lines only before first matched pattern

Tags: awk, files, text-formatting, replace, text

i need to insert the below lines (after variable substitution) before the first matched string which is `server  {` in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Variable:

```
website=www.hello.com
```

Block of lines:

```
server {
# Permanent redirect to www
server_name  ${website:4};
rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://$website/$1 permanent;
}
```

After variable substitution the block of lines to be inserted should look like the below:

```
server {
# Permanent redirect to www
server_name  hello.com;
rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.hello.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

there are 2 problems with the below attempt I made.

Problem 1: The code adds the block of lines before each (multiple) matched pattern and not just the first one.

Problem 2: The value of the variable `website` does not get substituted for `www.hello.com`

```
cat myattempt.sh
awk '
/server {/ {
    print "server {"
    print "# Permanent redirect to www"
    print "server_name  ${website:4};"
    print "rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://$website/$1 permanent;"
    print "}"
}
{ print }
' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf > /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.tmp
mv /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.tmp /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

In order to test my attempt create `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` as below

cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
http 
{
#  server   {
}

server  { 
}
}
```

Run myattempt.sh

Current Output:
cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
http 
{

server {
# Permanent redirect to www
server_name  ${website:4};
rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://$website/$1 permanent;
}

#  server   {
}

server {
# Permanent redirect to www
server_name  ${website:4};
rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://$website/$1 permanent;
}
server  { 
}
}
```

Expected output:

cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
http 
{

server {
# Permanent redirect to www
server_name  hello.com;
rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.hello.com/$1 permanent;
}

#  server   {
}

server  { 
}
}
```

Can you please suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be what you're trying to do:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

website=www.hello.com

new='
server {
# Permanent redirect to www
server_name  '"${website:4}"';
rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://'"$website"'/$1 permanent;
}
'

awk -v new="$new" '
    /server *\{/ && !f++ {
        print new
    }
    { print }
' "${@:-}"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file
http
{

server {
# Permanent redirect to www
server_name  hello.com;
rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.hello.com/$1 permanent;
}

#  server   {
}

server  {
}
}
```

Using `-v` to populate the awk variable `new` from  the shell variable of the same name will interpret escapee sequences so string like `\t` and `\n` would become literal tab and newline characters. If that's an issue use `ENVIRON[]` or `ARGV[]` to get the shell variable's value instead instead, see [how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if linking a [sed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148451/how-to-use-sed-to-replace-only-the-first-occurrence-in-a-file) to an awk question is considered rude, yet still :D

Also, the `www.` part is not printed because of [BASH parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).
You are telling it to start printing at index 4, thus first 4 characters are dropped.

Example:

```
$ foo='0123456789'; echo ${foo:3:5}
```

outputs `34567`.

Edit:
Alright, here is a self-contained eval, envsubst, awk solution.

It turns out multi-line find-replace is a PITA. For single-line search multi-line replace, one's best bet is using a language. I've come across awk examples for [find-replace with variables](https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/98834-search-replace-using-awk-variables.html) and [first occurence replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196791/replace-first-occurrence-of-text-using-awk) earlier than a `perl -pe` solution.

```
# Outputs a space delimetered, dollar-sign prepended text of variables
# e.g. args: 'foo' 'bar'
# output: '$foo $bar'
generate_multi_variable_string() {
    for item in $@; do
        # Prepend dollar-sign to the beginning of all variables, with an escape beforehand
        printf '$'
        printf "$item"
        printf ' '
    done
}

substitute_into_template() {
    template="$1"

    # Rest of the arguments as dollar-sign prepended and space delimetered
    variables="$(generate_multi_variable_string ${@:2})"

    # Export variables for envsubst command to properly function
    for item in ${@:2}; do
        eval "export local $item=\"\$$item\""
    done

    # Here-doc of template, into content of which provided variables are substituted
    envsubst "$variables" << EOF
$template
EOF
}

template='server {
# Permanent redirect to www
server_name  $website;
rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://$website/$1 permanent;'

website='www.hello.com'

match="server {"
replace="$(substitute_into_template "$template" website)"

cat nginx.conf | awk -v srch="$match" -v repl="$replace" '!x{x=sub(srch,repl,$0)} { print $0 }' > new-nginx.conf
```

Comment: @EdMorton you are right, thanks. I have revised the answer at the expense of not using sed. I admire elegancy of your answer it deserves the acceptance. Still, the challenge was worth the time I spent.